# Return custom error message when includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"

Tags: c#, .net, exception, svc

I'm using .net svc services with .Net framework 4.5 and for production purpose I have to set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to `false` in my `web.config` file.

However sometimes I need to have custom errors returned by my services.

I tried to use the `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler.ProvideFault` method to create a custom `FaultException` with no result, returned error message is always the generic message.

Is it possible to do it ? If yes how ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to return custom error messages.
Just wrap your message inside of a FaultException:

```
try
{
   // some calls go here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
}
```

Clients calling your service, see a clear message instead of the exception details, when an errors occurs.